# Need help on a Search Form

Tags: javascript

First post on this site and i am hoping someone can help me.
I created a search form on my site without a submit button. What i would like to happen is when the user clicks on the search bar it automatically redirects to a new page. I tried an attempt using Javascript but it does not seem to work. Hoping someone can help me out as i am not familiar with javascript.

```
<div id="searchbox">
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." onClick="redirect('www.triphub.ca')">
</div>


</style>
<script>function redirect('www.triphub.ca')
 {
    window.location.href = www.triphub.ca;
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could revise your function to

```
function redirect(url)
{ window.location.href = url; }
```

things inside `()` are variables and cannot be used as string (like you does wrapped words inside the single quote `'`, also you are missing the `}` at the end of your javascript

Answer (score 0):

Correct some of mistakes in your code.

```html
<div id="searchbox">
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." onClick="redirect('www.triphub.ca')">
</div>

<script>
 function redirect(url) {
    window.location.href = url;
 }
</script>
```